# When I used calloc to dynamically allocate a 1d array, am I supposed to get the same value or different value?

Tags: random, dynamic-allocation, calloc

I saw my friend's program.
When he used calloc and fill in 1d array with random gen. and compile their program, he is getting the same value of the array.

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>


srand(time(NULL));
int *n, s=10;

 one=(int*) calloc(s,sizeof(int));       
 for(m=0;m<s;m++)
 {
    o[m] =(rand()%20);               
    printf("%d\n",o[m]);
 }
free(one);
```

The outputs:

First run:
[image: First run]

Second run:
[image: Second run]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning to `o[m]` but printing out `one[m]`.

You also need to call `srand` at the start of your program to initialize the random sequence.

Comment: am I supposed to get the same value or different value?

Comment: The same value as what? The same value repeated ten times? The same value as your friend? No to both cases - you should be getting a random value between 0 and 19. It would be easier if you just showed your output.

Comment: when the program was run many times, they are getting the same value for the array...

Comment: That is what the `srand(time(NULL))` call is for, to initialize the random sequence to something different each time the program is run. Did you try it again after adding that? It produces different results each time on my system (once I changed all `one`s to `o`s and added a main function and some declarations).

Comment: yes...I keep getting different values when I run my program.  when I use the "calloc", will my random number change whenever I run the program?

Comment: The output looks right. Note that calloc has nothing to do with what the numbers are. calloc just allocates an area of memory to store the data. it is the rand call that generates the random numbers.